# Selenium python driver doesn't click or press the key for the button all the times

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, web-testing

I'm using selenium to get to YouTube and write something on the search bar and then press the button or press the enter key.

Both clicking or pressing a key does sometimes work, but sometimes it does not.
I tried to wait with `WebDriverWait`, and I even changed the waiting time from 10 to 20 seconds, but it didn't make any difference.

And if I add anything (like printing the new page title), it only shows me the first page title and not the title after the search.

Here is my code and what I tried:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def get_driver():
    firefox_options = Options()
    # firefox_options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\geckodriver.exe", options=firefox_options)
    driver.implicitly_wait(9)
    return driver

driver = get_driver()

driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')
search = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="search"]')
search.send_keys("python")
# search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER) #using the enter key # If I add nothing after this line it work
# searchbutton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="search-icon-legacy"]') # This also dose doesn't work
# searchbutton.click() # using the click method() #also dose not work
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="search-icon-legacy"]'))).click() # Sometimes work
# driver.implicitly_wait(10)
# print(driver.title) # This show me only the title of the first page not the one after the search
```

Is it because I use the Firefox webdriver (should I change to Chrome)?
Or is it because of my internet connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this working you need to click the search field input first, then add a short delay and then send the `Keys.ENTER` or click `search-icon-legacy` element.
So, this is not your fault, this is how YouTube webpage works. You may even call it a kind of bug. But since this webpage it built for human users it works good since human will never click on the input field and insert the search value there within zero time.
Anyway, the 2 following codes are working:
First.

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://www.youtube.com/"
driver.get(url)

search = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="search"]')))
search.click()
time.sleep(0.2)
search.send_keys("python")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="search-icon-legacy"]'))).click()
```

Second.

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://www.youtube.com/"
driver.get(url)

search = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="search"]')))
search.click()
time.sleep(0.2)
search.send_keys("python" + Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: It works exactly as I want and thank you for the tip about how YouTube works thank you very much

Comment: You are more than welcome! I always happy to help.